# How do I remove VS Code & settings from Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

VS Code is giving me some problems w/ formatting. I'd like to fully remove it and re-install.

However, each time I remove it and re-install, when I open it, it still remembers what I had opened.

This leads me to believe there's a settings file somewhere I'm missing.

Methods I've tried:

1. `sudo dpkg --purge code` & `sudo dpkg --remove code`
2. Uninstalling via `gdebi`
3. Full removal via `synaptic package manager`
4. Cussing, swearing, etc.

No dice. What am I missing?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try renaming `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`.

Or just move/delete the folders `~/.config/Code` and `~/.vscode`.

You may want to backup any code snippets in `~/.config/Code/User/snippets/`

See also: [Visual Studio Code User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace)

Comment: A+. Did the trick & fixed my VSCode bug. For posterity, I'll add that I also deleted `~/.vscode`. Not sure if that mattered, but didn't seem to hurt anything.

Comment: ^^to clarify, I deleted the entire `~/.config/Code` folder, not just the `settings.json`.

Comment: not exclusively to ubuntu but code or codium can create `settings.json` for each different project. Such as when typing `code .`  will create a `.vscode/settings.json` on that current directory. So to completely remove it might be good to `find -type d -name "vscode", to track where such files landed.
When using `codium` for example a global setting can be found in `$HOME/.var/app/com.vscodium.codium/config/VSCodium/User/settings.json` which also need to be deleted to have a full fresh install

Answer (score 23):

**Remove software**

- If you installed via Snap:

  `$sudo snap remove vscode`
- If you installed via apt:

  `$sudo apt-get purge code`
- If you installed via Ubuntu Software, open Ubuntu Software, look for the app in the installed category, and click on remove.

**Remove settings**

```
$cd ~ && rm -rf .vscode && rm -rf .config/Code
```

Comment: IMHO this should be the accepted answer, worked perfectly, also very precise

Comment: I had to run `$sudo snap remove code` (not vscode).

Answer (score 2):

Go to `/usr/share` and find the installation folder of VS Code, which is `code-insiders/` for an insider preview and `code` for a regular installation. Remove the folder which you don't find necessary.
Don't forget to remove the start menu entry in `/usr/share/applications/`

To remove the application settings go to your home folder and remove the `.vscode` folder.

---

Also if you want to backup your user settings before all this, try the settings sync extension.